# Communication between individual WatchOS App and iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, nativescript, watchos

Is it possible to set up a reliable connection passing data between an individual WatchOS App (i.e. that does not have a companion App) and an App of the same developer?

**The background is:** We want to setup a WatchOS App that serves as heart rate data generator (pushing samples to our iOS App). The problem is: The iOS side is implemented with Nativescript that only allows for Objective-C when adding a WatchOS App (not to mention that this feature is still in beta phase). So the idea is to set up an individual WatchOS Swift App without companion and establish some connection (WatchConnectivity seems not possible here). We rather not want to rely on an internet connection in order to push the samples from the watch to our backend and back to the iOS App.

The structure of the samples we need to pass should allow for a numeric value and a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since watchOS4, [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) is supported on watchOS as well, so you should be able to communicate between any iPhone app and a standalone watchOS app using CoreBluetooth.

Comment: Looks promising! Will that make it through the AppStore Review?